# Is it possible to bundle a kext in a Application?

Tags: java, macos, installation, kernel-extension

I have a Mac OS X application that requires a kext (also built by me). I would like to "bundle" the kext into the application, so that when the user run the application, the kext is automatically loaded (of course, a prompt for administrator password may be shown). Is it possible, or do I need to install the kext at install time?

Answer (score 1):

You can install it from your app. You'll need to use the Service Management framework to run a task at elevated privileges (written in C or Obj-C). This can then install the kext.

Your helper tool should be an executable that runs at elevated privileges to perform the action of installing your kext on behalf of your app.

Steps:

1. Include the Kext and the helper tool as resources in your app bundle
2. Create a helper tool to do the work for you. Your helper tool will need to copy your kext to the /System/Extensions directory. You'll need to copy it at elevated privileges. Get your helper tool to call kextload to install it.
3. You'll need to code-sign the helper tool and the app, and put the relevant entries for the Service Management framework in the info.plist for both the helper and the main app.

The Apple developer documentation for this is absolutely atrocious. Good luck. You will probably have to do this all in Objective-C or C, not Java, as you have to use C-libraries such as Security Framework and Service Manager, plus code signing.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to bundle it! I run a script which ask for the root password and then proceeds to install the kext. The only problem is that the location of the bundled kext must be known in advance (I must 'cd' to them); so the application must be put on a predefined location, otherwise it won't work.

Comment: The script can surely find out where *it* is and thus deduce the location of the kext via a relative path; alternatively pass the location of the kext to the script as an argument?

Comment: The kext is 'bundled' inside the application, which in turn can be put everywhere. If you know a way to deduce the current folder please let me know.

Comment: Depends: How are you launching the script, and what kind of script is it?

Comment: Inside the MyApp.app, I have edited the Info.plist so that the execution starts with my script. Apparently, when the user double clicks the application (starts the app) the script is run from the User home folder instead of the MyApp folder... (maybe I should post this as a question...)

Comment: I assume this is a shell script then? If so, you can get the path to the script via the $0 variable.